# actionscript 3: how to access to elements of an array created in a loop dynamically

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, dynamic

In the library of the .fla file I have a square exported as Class "cuad" on frame 1

I want to create an Array with 100 squares so as to move them later

So I do like this:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i<100;i++)
{
var cuad_mc = new cuad();
addChild(cuad_mc);                      
myArray.push("cuad_mc");
trace(myArray[i]);
}
```

I have a runtime error

Comment: you are pushing Strings into the array, not "cuad" objects. Other than that the code looks fine, show us how you created the array itself.

Comment: var myArray = new Array();

Comment: also looks fine, please post the entire error

Comment: For example if I wan to move elements to x=50

I do:

    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;

    var myArray = new Array();

    for (var i:uint = 0; i<100;i++)
    {
    var cuad_mc = new cuad();
    addChild(cuad_mc);                      
    myArray.push("cuad_mc");
    trace(myArray[i]);
   
    TweenMax.to(myArray[i], 1, {x:50, alpha:1, overwrite:true});       
    }

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Did not find alpha propiety in the String and there is not any value predetermined

Comment: I see, give me a minute, i'll write an answer

Answer (score 3):

The error you experience is

> Error #1069: Did not find alpha propiety in the String and there is not any value predetermined

The problem comes from your line

```
myArray.push("cuad_mc");
```

What you are doing here is pushing a String Object into your Array, not the cuad Object you want. String Objects don't have Alpha values, or x values.

What you want to do is

```
myArray.push(cuad_mc);
```

cuad_mc (without the " quotation marks) is a reference to the object you just created.

This should solve your problem. I also recommend using Vectors instead of Array if you only need to store one type of Object. Like this:

```
var myArray:Vector<cuad> = new Vector<cuad>();
for(var i:int=0;i<100;i++){
    var cuad_mc:cuad = new cuad();
    addChild(cuad_mc);
    myArray.push(cuad_mc);
    trace(myArray[i]);
}
```

Vectors are just like Arrays, but they only allow **one specific type**, so that a situation like yours doesn't occur.

Comment: I think I have an error:  import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var myArray = new Array();

for (var i:uint = 0; i<100;i++)
{
   var cuad_mc = new cuad();
   addChild(cuad_mc);                      
   myArray.push(cuad_mc);
   trace(myArray[i]);
   
   TweenMax.to(myArray[30], 1, {x:50, alpha:1, overwrite:true});       
}

Comment: you can't manipulate objects before you have created them. when the loop is still at 1 (i is 0) you try to manipulate object 30 in the array, which you haven't created yet.